# How to create recursive tree-like data structure in java using Map<String, T>?

Tags: java, recursive-datastructures

I have a mind-block when trying to create data-structure that follows the pattern:

`Map<String, T>` is a main building block and `T` is either `Map<String, T>` or as terminal operator `List<String>`. Is it possible to build anything similar in `Java`, this idea comes from functional languages like `F#` or `Haskell`-like.

I searched `SO` but so far couldn't find anything that match my idea in `Java`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class T {
...
}
public class NonTerminal extends T {
    private Map<String,T> map = new HashMap<>();
...
}
public class Terminal extends T {
    private List<String> list;
---
}
```

Comment: I'd go with an interface rather than an abstract class. There is no need to limit inheritance for this.

Comment: I'd add private constructor to the abstract class and put the subclasses as static nested classes to make it look like an algebraic data type.

Answer (score 3):

Recreating functional programming stuff in Java isn't really a good idea (at least not in Java 8, I don't know about Java 11).

You can do something like this:

```
class EitherMapOrList {
    private Map<String, EitherMapOrList> map;
    private List<String> list;

    public EitherMapOrList(Map<String, EitherMapOrList> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public EitherMapOrList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    // you can remove the optionals here and use null directly.
    public Optional<Map<String, EitherMapOrList>> getMap() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(map);
    }

    public Optional<List<String>> getList() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(list);
    }
}
```

And then create a `Map<String, EitherMapOrList>`.

But I would imagine it would be a pain to use this thing in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You could use just a single `Map<String, KeyOrValue>` where the value could be a marker interface with two implementations

```
interface KeyOrValue {}

class Key implements KeyOrValue {
    private String key;
}

class Value implements KeyOrValue {
    private List<String> values;
}
```

You could then just create a lookup method which recursivly calls itself and then returns the value once it has reached the end:

```
private final Map<String, KeyOrValue> map = ...

public List<String> getValues(String key) {
    KeyOrValue keyOrValue = map.get(key);
    if(keyOrValue instanceof Key) {
        // is a key, so use recursion to get the value
        key = ((Key) keyOrValue).key;
        return getValues(key);
    } else if(keyOrValue instanceof Value) {
        // is a value, so just return the value it holds
        return ((Value) keyOrValue).values;
    } else {
        // no mapping was found for "key"
        return null;
    }
}
```

You could do the same without recursion too:

```
public List<String> getValues(String key) {
    KeyOrValue keyOrValue;
    List<String> values = null;
    do {
        keyOrValue = map.get(key);
        if(keyOrValue instanceof Key) {
            // is a key, so iterate further
            key = ((Key) keyOrValue).key;
        } else if(keyOrValue instanceof Value) {
            // is a value, so get the values out and set the key to null to break the loop
            values = ((Value) keyOrValue).values;
            key = null;
        }
    } while(key != null);

    // return the values, may be null due to nothing being found
    return values;
}
```

---

The marker interface is not really needed though, you can get the same outcome if you just use `Map<String, Object>` where the value could either be a `String` or a `List<String>` and then the `instanceof` checks would have to be adapted too, but I like the approach the way with an `interface` more

Answer (score 2):

If you want to translate haskell

```
data Map a = Branch { key :: String, value :: a, left :: Map a, right :: Map a} | MapNul
```

to java you can go with:

```
class Map<T> {
    String key;
    T value;
    Map<T> left;
    Map<T> right;
}
```

you do not need `MapNul` in java because you can use `null` instead of it.